# How to update one entity from another through workflow

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have two entities Kitchen and Medical. I want a workflow where when a record in created in Medical, a similar record is created in Kitchens. It sounds very simple and I have been working with workflows.

My workflow is based on entity Medical and it starts on create form event. I have added only one condition which says 
CREATE: Kitchen.
and i have related all the fields of kitchen with fields in medical form. But the workflow is not working.

Can someone help me in logic or anything.

The workflow is working now, but the issue is that I have to start it manually after I save the form. Can it start automatically on save?

Comment: Is the problem that the workflow do not start, or do you get an error? If the workflow do not start the problem could be that the async service has stopped. If not you should be able to see the error under "workflows".

Comment: Svendberg you are right the service was stopped. Thank you.
but the issue is that I have to start it manually after I save the form. Can it start automatically on save?

Comment: how the workflow gets triggered is set on the workflow properties page. sounds like you have it set to ondemand?

Comment: the problem has been solved please read my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My asynchronous services were stopped, after starting them the workflow worked. I changed the workflow to work on When the record is created rather than When the record is saved even. Now it is running automatically on save.